# Can't $f(x)$ be negative here?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, contest-math

The following question was asked in JEE Advanced 2020.

**Question:**

Let $b$ be a nonzero real number. Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function such that $f(0)=1$. If the derivative $f'$ of $f$ satisfies the equation $$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{b^2+x^2},$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then which of the following statements is/are True?

A) If $b\gt0$, then $f$ is an increasing function.

B) If $b\lt0$, then $f$ is a decreasing function.

C) $f(x)f(-x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

D) $f(x)-f(-x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

**My Attempt:**

Positive or negative nature of $f'(x)$ is dependent on the positive or negative nature of $f(x),$ not $b$.

Solving the given differential equation, we get,

$$\ln|f(x)|=\frac1{|b|}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{|b|}\right)$$

(Constant of integration is zero here)

Therefore, $$|f(x)|=e^{\frac1{|b|}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{|b|}\right)}\\ \implies f(x)=\pm e^{\frac1{|b|}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{|b|}\right)} $$

I can see that option C) is correct. Option D) is incorrect.

How to decide for option A) and B)?

**Official Answer is A,C.**

Comment: Notice that $f(0)=1$, so it must be plus instead of plus-minus

Comment: @Dqrksun thankyou very much

Answer (score 2):

A) is obviously true, by your own argument. That the conclusion is true also for $b<0$ does not change the logical value for $b>0$. One could also mention that as $f(x)=0$ is a solution of the DE, every other solution has a constant sign.

With $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)f(-x)=f'(x)f(-x)-f(x)f'(-x)=0$$ you can derive C) without computing the solution formula.

C) then directly contradicts D)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> A) $f$ is increasing for $b > 0$.

This indicates that that the gradient should be positive. Is this true when you judge the range of $f'$?

> B) $f$ is decreasing for $b < 0$

Similiar judgement as A), but consider whether the gradient is negative?

> D) $f(x) - f(-x) = 0$

Is the function, $\tan^{-1}(g(x))$, an even function? (Another Hint: $\tan^{-1}(-x) = -\tan^{-1}(x))$

Also, $f(0) = 1 \to e^0 = 1$ (just pointed out in the comments).